# Meteor + React how to set the value of a lot of input elements and modify them after

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

I'm new to meteor and react.  Let's say I have this in my react component:

```
getMeteorData() {
    var myForm = ProjectForm.findOne({_id:this.props.router.params._id});
    var projects = ProjectForm.find({});
    return {myForm:myForm,projects:projects};
    // doing a console.log(myForm); would give you something like
    /*
    input1:my text 1
    input2:some other text
    input3:something else
    etc....
    */
  },
  renderListProjects() {

    return this.data.projects.map(function(projectform,i) {
      return <li key={"li"+i}><a href={Meteor.absoluteUrl()+'project/' + projectform.username +'/' +projectform._id} key={"a"+i}>Project {projectform._id}</a></li>;
    });
  },
  getInitialState() {
     return Projects.findOne({this.props.router.params._id}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}});
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <ul>{this.renderListProjects()}</ul>
      <form>
         <span>Hello this is some text</span>
         <input type="text" ref="input1" />
         <p>Blah blah this is boring</p>
         <input type="text" ref="input2" />
         <img src="image-of-a-kangaroo.png" />
         <input type="text" ref="input3" />
         <ul>
            <li>Buy brocolli</li>
            <li>Buy oregano</li>
            <li>Buy milk</li>
         </ul>
         <input type="text" ref="input4" />
         ...
         <textarea ref="input100"></textarea>
         <input type="text" ref="input101" />
         <p><strong>Yes, I like pizza!</strong>  But my porcupine gets sick eating pizza.</p>
         ...
      </form>
      </div>
    );
```

What I want to do is assign the values of `this.data.myForm` to each of the form fields in the render() function.  But when I do something like `<input type="text" ref="input1" value={this.data.myForm.input1} />`, and I go to my web browser and put my cursor on that field, I am NOT able to modify the value.  Pressing the keys on my keyboard will not change the value of that input field.  Additionally, I have about 250 input fields in this html form.  I really don't want to do any data entry.  I would much rather just use some kind of loop to iterate through the `this.data.myForm` and assign it to the corresponding form fields.  But when I tried to do this, I get problems about the DOM not being found or it's not loaded.  So I tried writing some code in componentDidMount(), but then I got other errors.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to efficiently bind all my `this.data.myForm` data to my form fields AND allow me to edit the form fields after?

**Additional Requirements**

1. If someone clicks on link1 from the `renderListProjects` then clicks on link2 from the `renderlistProjects`, then the form must show the value of link2's `projectform._id`.
2. In the DOM, an `href="project/_id"` attribute must exist for SEO and for WCAG compliance.

**Attempts**

I tried to redefine renderListProjects as

```
  renderListProjects() {
    var pj = this
    return this.data.projects.map(function(projectform,i) {
      return <li key={"li"+i}><a onClick={pj.click(projectform._id)} href={Meteor.absoluteUrl()+'project/' + projectform.username +'/' +projectform._id} key={"a"+i}>Project {projectform._id}</a></li>;
    });
  },
click(id) {
    var currentApp = ProjectForm.findOne({_id:id}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}});
    this.setState({input36:input36});
  },
```

But when I run my meteor+react project, my browser crashes because some kind of infinite loop is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code solved the problem

```
getMeteorData() {
    var myForm = ProjectForm.findOne({_id:this.props.router.params._id});
    var projects = ProjectForm.find({});
    return {myForm:myForm,projects:projects};
    // doing a console.log(myForm); would give you something like
    /*
    input1:my text 1
    input2:some other text
    input3:something else
    etc....
    */
  },
  clickLoadForm(appId)
  {
    var currentApp = Projects.findOne({appId}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}});
    var state = new Object();
    var refs = this.refs;
    Object.keys(refs).map(function(prop,index){
      state[prop] = typeof currentApp[prop] == 'undefined' ? "" : currentApp[prop];
    });
    this.setState(state);
  },
  handleChange: function(e) {
    if(!e.target.id) return;
    if(typeof e.target.id == 'undefined') return;
    var state = new Object();
    state[e.target.id] = e.target.value;

    this.setState(state);
  },
  renderListProjects() {

    return this.data.projects.map(function(projectform,i) {
      return <li key={"li"+i}><a onClick={_this.clickLoadForm.bind(_this,projectform._id)} href={Meteor.absoluteUrl()+'project/' +projectform._id} key={"a"+i}>Project {projectform._id}</a></li>;
    });
  },
  getInitialState() {
     return Projects.findOne({this.props.router.params._id}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}});
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <ul>{this.renderListProjects()}</ul>
      <form>
         <span>Hello this is some text</span>
         <input type="text" ref="input1" id="input1" onChange={this.handleChange} />
         <p>Blah blah this is boring</p>
         <input type="text" ref="input2" id="input2" onChange={this.handleChange} />
         <img src="image-of-a-kangaroo.png" />
         <input type="text" ref="input3" id="input3" onChange={this.handleChange} />
         <ul>
            <li>Buy brocolli</li>
            <li>Buy oregano</li>
            <li>Buy milk</li>
         </ul>
         <input type="text" ref="input4" id="input4" onChange={this.handleChange} />
         ...
         <textarea ref="input100" id="input100" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
         <input type="text" ref="input101" id="input101" onChange={this.handleChange} />
         <p><strong>Yes, I like pizza!</strong>  But my porcupine gets sick eating pizza.</p>
         ...
      </form>
      </div>
    );
```

To summarize, my changes were:

1. created a `renderListProjects()` function
2. created the `clickLoadForm()` function and used it in the `renderListProjects()`
3. created the `handleChange()` function and made sure it's references via onChange for each element in `render()`
4. made sure every element in `render()` has an id that's the same as the ref

Answer (score 0):

What you created is what React calls an [controlled input](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components). This means that React has declared your value in the inputs to correspond to whatever `this.data.myForm.input1` points to.

What you need to do in order to be able to change an input field is to add an onChange handler that takes care of updating the value. The [documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html) is quite straight forward but I added a small example below to illustrate it.

```
class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      myForm: {
        inputs: [
          {value: 1}, {value: 2}, {value: 3}
        ]
      }
    };
  }
  onChange = (index, event) => {
    let inputs = this.state.myForm.inputs.slice(0);
    inputs[index] = {
      value: parseInt(event.target.value, 10)
    };

    this.setState({
      myForm: {
        inputs: inputs
      }
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (<form>
      {this.state.myForm.inputs.map((input, index) => {
        return (<input onChange={this.onChange.bind(null, index)} value={input.value} key={index} />);
      }, this)}
      </form>);
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(<Form />, document.querySelector('#c'));
```

Comment: I tried something similar with the `getInitialState()`.  However, I have an issue because my `this.state` is populated by `ProjectForm.Collections.findOne({_id:this.props.router.params._id})` .  So when I click on any hyper link on my page which keeps the `_id` component of the URL, none of the controlled inputs in my form changes to the values of a different ProjectForm corresponding to the new `_id`. How do I get around that problem?

Comment: You would have to rerender the entire form with the new data. So something like this `<a onClick={renderForm.bind(newId)}>{newId}</a>`.

Comment: I might need a bit more instruction about `renderForm.bind()` since I'm new to react development.  Couldn't really find any documentation on this specific call.  Can you point me to some online material that can give me more details? Thanks

Comment: Using `.bind` is normal JavaScript and the `renderForm` method was something I just made up. The point was that you need to re-render the entire form when you click on a link that should change the form. You can find the concept here -> http://jsbin.com/bocehimota/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: hi limelights, thanks for keeping up with my comments.  I had trouble connecting the dots between your jsbin example and my actual problem.  So I updated my question with more sample code and more requirements for my problem.  Are you able to offer more constructive feedback for me? Been struggling....

Comment: Or if you are able to answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34459824/simple-meteor-react-iron-router-crud-application .  Answering that question will help me solve the problem posed on this current web page.

Comment: or this question here, which actually has working code for you to modify http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34464621/cannot-update-during-an-existing-state-transition